# ¿Cómo limitar el ancho del navegador con css?

Tags: css3

Estoy tratando de limitar el ancho mínimo de la ventana del navegador a 600px,pero no logro hacerlo, estuve tratando de hacerlo a través de `min-width` en el elemento `body` y el elemento "html", lo siguiente es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

html,body{
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


 #map{
       min-width: 600px;
       height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
  }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>


  <div class="contenedor">

     <div id="map"></div>

  </div>

    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDETpwRQsNoaPJQOD6-unMBW7rr2Sdrfdk&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Quiero lograr que al llegar la ventana a un ancho de 600 píxeles este ya no se pueda hacer más chico.

Comment: Con css no se puede hacer eso y dudo que se pueda con javascript y aunque fuera posible es una malísima idea, el control del navegador debe tenerlo siempre el usuario

Comment: posiblemente relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/160783/81450

Answer (score 1):

¿es esto lo que esperas como funcionalidad?

Abre una nueva venta y cambia el tamño a 500px:

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Crear Ventanawindow</button>
<button onclick="resizeWin()">Cambiar tamaño</button>
```

Código JS:

```
<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");
}

function resizeWin() {
    myWindow.resizeTo(250, 250);
    myWindow.focus();
}
</script>
```

Hasta donde sé, con CSS podrás dar estilo a los componentes dentro de la ventana del navegador, para poder manipular la ventana  o el DOM, será con Java Script o incluso JQuery.

Comment: lo voy a comprobar en este momento

Comment: Faltaría poner `resizable=no` para que no se pueda cambiar de tamaño en cuanto se abra la ventana. Pero ojo, algunos navegadores dejaron de soportarlo para ser más accesibles.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto en tu body, a mí me resultó

```
<body onLoad="window.resizeTo(500,730)">
```

Comment: Puedes editar tu respuesta haciendo click en [edit]. Te recomiendo leer [answer] y hacer el [tour]

Comment: Bienvenido. El código no se mostraba correctamente porque las publicaciones utilizan un lenguaje de marcado, Markdown y también soportan algunas etiquetas HTML. Con el formato correcto las etiquetas se muestran como código. Deberías aprender a usar el sitio.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta utilizando las media de `css`, de la siguiente manera:

```
#map{
    width:100%;
    height: 400px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px){
   #map{
       width:600px;
   }
}
```

Comment: no funciono,cambie lo que me dijsite pero cuando hago mas pequeña la ventana del navegador,este no respeta el min-width y se minimiza mas alla del tamaño establecido

Comment: Edite el codigo, hize otra opcion pero esta vez sin utilizar min-width, utilizando las media query de css

Comment: y funciono ?? es que casi no se ocupar los media queries,serias tan amable de guiarme

Comment: Al usar @media screen and (max-width:600px) le indicas al navegador que al momento de la ventana del navegador sea menor que 600px se va a aplicar una propiedad a un determinado elemento, max-width indica un maximo del tamaño del width de la pantalla, osea que si es mayor que el width establecido (600px) lo que este dentro de la query no se va a aplicar