# ¿Cómo predefino el tamaño de la ventana del navegador desde mi código?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy buscando como hacer que mi pagina cuando la ejecute, el navegador ya sea chrome, ie, firefox, se abra junto con la pagina a un tamaño predeterminado, he estado buscando pero no en encontrado respuesta alguna, muchas gracias!

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Mi pagina</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por una cuestión de experiencia de usuario no es posible cambiar el tamaño de la ventana del navegador desde hace tiempo (+5 años).

**.1.**  Sí es posible abrir una ventana emergente desde una pagina y cambiarle el tamaño

1) con el tamaño ya puesto

```
  <script TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript">
     miVentanaEmergente = window.open("http://dominio/pagina", "elNombreDeMiventana", "width=640, height=480");
  </script>
```

2) abrir y cambiar tamaño

```
  <script TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript">
     miVentanaEmergente = window.open("http://dominio/pagina", "elNombreDeMiventana", "resizable");
     miVentanaEmergente.resizeTo(640,480);
  </script>
```

**Nota:** según el navegador, la configuración y las extensiones que tengas puede que falle o abra una pestaña.

Un truco para sortear esto es chequear si la ventana se creo y sino cambiar de location

```
l.href = "https://www.google.com";
l.target = "Nueva ventana";
var wOpen = window.open(l.href, l.target);
if (wOpen == null || typeof(wOpen)=='undefined') {
   document.location = l.href);
 }
```

**.2.**  En navegadores antiguos (donde si es posible cambiar el tamaño de la ventana)
Safari 3, Firefox 3, IE 6, IE 7, Opera 5.5 o 6 creo fue el último

1)

```
 <body onload="window.resizeTo(640,480)">
```

2)

```
<html>
  <script TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript">
     window.resizeTo(640,480);
  </script>
</html>
```

**.3.**  Si es tu propia computadora:
Podes editar el acceso directo (o copiar y crear uno nuevo) y darle los parámetros.

Chrome:

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --window-position=200,50 --window-size=1400,900`

ó

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --window-position=200,50 --window-size=1400,900`

Firefox;
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -height 480 -width 640`

**Nota:** 
Si los navegadores estaban maximizados antes de cerrarse, según la versión de windows se abren pequeño y se agrandan (o no)