# Centrar Ventana modal window.open con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Quisiera saber como centrar una ventana modal hecha con window.open de manera horizontal y verticalmente, lo que tengo es esto:

```
 var myWindow ="wa.me/…?"; 
 window.open(myWindow, "", "width=600,height=400");
```

Comment: Hola @Noe Muñoz. Debes poner todo el código para que te podamos ayudar. Lo que tengas echo HTML y JS. Saludos!

Comment: En sí el código es muy largo, te voy a colocar lo que hace parte de la modal: "var myWindow ="https://wa.me/57"+data.celular+"?text=Buen%20día,%20le%20escribe%20Andrés%20Holguín%20de%20Punto%20Clásicc,%20ropa%20clásica%20para%20hombres,%20usted%20está%20una%20interesado%20en%20nuestros%20productos?";
                window.open(myWindow, "", "width=600,height=400");"

Comment: tradicionalmente se le agregaba `top=xxx, left=yyy` a las features calculando la mitad de la pantalla menos la mitad del ancho y alto, pero ya no hacen caso los navegadores  por cuestiones de experiencia de usuario, mas info -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/160783/81450

Comment: Hola alo Malbarez, hay forma de hacerlo tal véz con un tipo de align: center, o algo parecido?

Comment: la respuesta es "undefined" =P, cada navegador suele hacer lo que le place, abren tabs, no las abren , las abren pero en "algún lado" creo que delegan al manejador de ventanas del sistema operativo el tema de donde posicionarla para que no moleste u oculte a las otras aplicaciones/ventanas.

Comment: para alinearla a la página tendrías que abrir un modal popup pero dentro de la misma página onda bootstrap modal

Comment: Pero no sería responsiva, :(

Comment: Ahorita lo hice como me dijiste, pero si la abro en una pantalla más grande se ve mal, porque ella esta adaptada a la pantalla en que se alineó.

Comment: dentro de la misma página si, tomas el tamaño del viewport(ventana) del UA (navegador) y la centras dandole un minimo y un máximo

Comment: Cómo lo haría? :V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
<script>
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
    // Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox
    var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : window.screenX;
    var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : window.screenY;

    var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
    var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

    var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
    var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
    var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

    // Puts focus on the newWindow
    if (window.focus) {
        newWindow.focus();
    }
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="PopupCenter('http://www.google.com.ar','xtf','600','400');">Open</button>
```

Por favor, lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Para poder formular tus preguntas correctamente en el futuro. Espero que te sirva la respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: Podrías por favor mostrar el código un poco más limpio?

Comment: @Noe Muñoz no te entiendo. A que te referís con con el código mas limpio?

Comment: El código que me pasaste es algo enredado, puedes pasarlo un pococ más "fácil de entender"?

Comment: @Noe Muñoz Disculpa, estaba leyendo las normas de la comunidad. Para explicarte detalladamente todas las dudas que tengas vamos a dejar una larga cola de comentarios! Según las normas eres libre de compartir algún medio de contacto como correo electrónico en tu perfil. Si lo deseas puedes hacer eso y con gusto me comunico y te explico todas las dudas. Saludos!

Comment: Claro, escríbeme a noemunozr@gmail.com